# Conditionally selecting one row from a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
   Table A
----------------
  ID   | Data...
----------------
   1      ...
   2      ...
   3      ...
```

```
   Table B
---------------------------------------------------------
  ID   | table_a_id | status | status_change_dt | default
---------------------------------------------------------
   1        2           1        2019-08-01         0
   2        2           0           null            1
   3        2           0           null            0
```

`status` in `Table B` could be 1 or 0. There is also the possibility that the `status` could be out of date - anything over 30 days is considered unreliable.

This is where the `default` column comes in. You can think of this column as a fallback option to `status` when `status` is older than 30 days or no `status` is equal to 1.

I've tried the following but it always returns two rows:

```
SELECT 
    table_a.*, table_b.* 
FROM 
    table_a 
INNER JOIN 
    table_b
ON 
    ((table_b.status = 1 AND table_b.status_change_dt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) OR table_b.default=1) 
WHERE 
    table_a.id = 2
```

I am expecting this to return no more than one row from `Table B`. In this case, row 2 would be our fall back because the `status_change_dt` exceeds 30 days in row 1. However, this is returning both rows in my query.

Comment: Please post the desired result.

Comment: Why only row 2?

Comment: @P.Salmon I am expecting only one row from `Table B`. Let me update the expectations...

Comment: That I get but what's the logic for the preferred row - or will any one row do.

Comment: The idea is that `status=1 AND days < 30` would take precedence while selecting a single row, but if that condition fails, `default` would become our fall back. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Erm your query works fine..

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm banging my head. Let me try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread your code - you need to join on id as well as other conditions.
It's no clear from your question whether you can have many rows where status = 1 and a date within range or if you can have many rows with a default = 1.

To prefer a status = 1 and date within range and if no such record exists then pick default = 1 then a union with an existence test in the second select should do . NB if neither exist then nothing will be returned.

If you only have 1 row with status = 1 and a date and 1 row with a default = 1 then this may do.

```
SELECT table_a.*, table_b.*
FROM table_a 
INNER JOIN table_b on table_b.table_a_id = table_a.id
    and (table_b.status = 1 AND table_b.status_change_dt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
WHERE table_a.id = 2 
union
select table_a.*, table_b.*
FROM table_a 
INNER JOIN table_b on table_b.table_a_id = table_a.id 
              and `default` = 1
where table_A.id = 2 and not exists
            (select 1 from table_b where table_b.table_a_id = table_a.id  and  
               (table_b.status = 1 AND table_b.status_change_dt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
             );
```

Comment: This was the right answer. Thank you for spending time on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row:

```
select a.*, b.*
from table_a a join
     table_b b
     on a.id = b.table_a_id
where a.id = 2 
order by (status_change_dt is not null) desc,
         (status_change_dt > curdate() - interval 30 day) desc,
         default desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` will limit the entire result to one record. What if I am selecting multiple records from `Table A`, and only expect there to be a single record from my `JOIN`?

Comment: @user0000001 . . . Then you wouldn't be filtering on `a_id`, which is presumably the primary key of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way of doing it would be:

```
Select a.*, b.*
FROM a INNER JOIN b
ON a.id = b.table_a_id
WHERE a.id = nn /*(Your hard choice or parameter i.e. 2)*/
AND b.id = nn /*(Your hard choice or parameter i.e. 1)*/
AND ((b.status = 1
AND b.status_change_dt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) OR b.default = 1)
```

The INNER JOIN and the WHERE clause placing a resticcion on b.id will produce a single record. The conditions you place into the ON clause would be placed in the WHERE clause.
Hopping it'll work for you.